# Simplify Javascript syntax for these functions

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

What's the best way to simplify the syntax for these combined function?

```js
var returndateyes = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_0");
var returndateno = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_1");
var returndatecal = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3C4945224E184A9B9E3B6ABBB6D8A423_scope");
var multitripyes = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_0");
var multitripno = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_1");
var secondtripdate = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FB04828F69244ADB822E8C1CD36477EE_scope");
var thirdtripdate = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FDE38F6B8C2E4A788728550A2DECA132_scope");

    returndatecal.style.display = "none";
    secondtripdate.style.display = "none";
    thirdtripdate.style.display = "none";
   
    returndateyes.onclick = function () {
    if (returndateyes.checked) {
      returndatecal.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      returndatecal.style.display = "none";
    }  
  }
 
    returndateno.onclick = function () {
    if (returndateno.checked) {
      returndatecal.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      returndatecal.style.display = "block";
    }  
  }

    multitripyes.onclick = function () {
    if (multitripyes.checked) {
      secondtripdate.style.display = "block";
   thirdtripdate.style.display = "block"; 
    }
    else {
      secondtripdate.style.display = "none";
   thirdtripdate.style.display = "none"
    }  
  }
  
    multitripno.onclick = function () {
    if (multitripno.checked) {
      secondtripdate.style.display = "none";
   thirdtripdate.style.display = "none"; 
    }
    else {
      secondtripdate.style.display = "block";
   thirdtripdate.style.display = "block"
    }  
  }
```

It works but could use some syntax advice!

Comment: You might be better off asking this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review, so is more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var returndateyes = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_0"), 
returndateno = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_1"), 
returndatecal = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3C4945224E184A9B9E3B6ABBB6D8A423_scope"), 
multitripyes = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_0"), 
multitripno = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_1"), 
secondtripdate = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FB04828F69244ADB822E8C1CD36477EE_scope"), 
thirdtripdate = document.getElementById("content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FDE38F6B8C2E4A788728550A2DECA132_scope");

returndatecal.style.display = "none";
secondtripdate.style.display = "none";
thirdtripdate.style.display = "none";

returndateyes.onclick = function() {
    returndatecal.style.display = returndateyes.checked ? "block" : "none";
};

returndateno.onclick = function() {
    returndatecal.style.display = returndateno.checked ? "none" : "block";
};

multitripyes.onclick = function() {
    multitripyes.checked ? (secondtripdate.style.display = "block", thirdtripdate.style.display = "block") : (secondtripdate.style.display = "none", thirdtripdate.style.display = "none");
};
multitripno.onclick = function() {
    multitripno.checked ? (secondtripdate.style.display = "none", thirdtripdate.style.display = "none") : (secondtripdate.style.display = "block", thirdtripdate.style.display = "block");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Sagar Jajoriya!

Comment: Fixed, my computer is acting up because of a video render!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

- Create a map of all the checkbox with those elements which should be displayed/hidden based on the checkbox checked value
- Iterate that map to bind the events.

**Sample below**

```js
var checkboxToDateToMap = {
  "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_0": ["content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3C4945224E184A9B9E3B6ABBB6D8A423_scope"],
  "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_7C9F9E2157994A2A84FE73D9389C76AAscope_1": ["content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3C4945224E184A9B9E3B6ABBB6D8A423_scope"],
  "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_0": ["content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FB04828F69244ADB822E8C1CD36477EE_scope", "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FDE38F6B8C2E4A788728550A2DECA132_scope"],
  "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_3A796ED80E744BDD9720E4ADAC8DCC5Escope_1": ["content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FB04828F69244ADB822E8C1CD36477EE_scope", "content_1_form_F5E9D36B22E24CA2A7A8E858D4952AEF_field_FDE38F6B8C2E4A788728550A2DECA132_scope"]
}

Object.keys(checkboxToDateToMap).forEach(function(checkboxElementId) {
   
    //first hide all dates
    checkboxToDateToMap[ checkboxElementId ].forEach( function( elementId ) {
        document.getElementById( elementId ).display = "none";
    });

    //get a handle to checkbox
    var checkboxEl = document.getElementById( checkboxElementId );

    //add the event listener to the checkbox
    checkboxEl.addEventListener( "click", function() {
        checkboxToDateToMap[ checkboxElementId ].forEach( function( elementId ) {
            document.getElementById( elementId ).display = checkboxEl.checked ? "block" : "none";
        });
    });
});
```